# Responive background-url in Bootstrap Col div empty

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, background-image

I'm building a site for a client right now. I've use Bootstrap in the past so I'm somewhat familiar with how to set up a Responsive grid.

So here's my issue. The client wants some divs to be animated. So I'm going to do that with CSS3. Since I want to be able to layer elements on top of eachother I figured I start by setting the BG of the div to my first image in the stack.

So okay here's the problem. I've got four col divs next to each other like so.

```
<div class="row center-block">    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 " >
      <div id="buttonWrapper1"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ">
        <div id="buttonWrapper2"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ">
         <div id="buttonWrapper3"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ">
         <div id="buttonWrapper4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS for this look something this

```
#buttonWrapper1 {   
    background-image: url(../img/image-button-01.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

#buttonWrapper2 {   
    background-image: url(../img/image-button-02.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

#buttonWrapper3 {
    background-image: url(../img/image-button-03.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

#buttonWrapper4 {   
    background-image: url(../img/image-button-03.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

The problem is that nothing with appear, unless I set the height and width explicitly. Which I don't want to do, because this is supposed to be a responsive grid.

And when I do this, max-width: `300px; height: 300px;` The row starts to expand down (meaning it pads the bottom of the row). (I don't want that). When I try to set `background-size: contain;` that sorts of works, but still pads the bottom of the row. When I set `background-size: cover` it blows all the cols out and looks messy.

Any thoughts how to fix this? I just want to be able to set the BG images of the divs and to have them scale proportionately.

Thanks in advance. Should I try a different approach, can I sue JavaScript to fix this?

Comment: It is hard to help you without any working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNpYeR

The code is a bit messy but you should get the idea.  The only caveat here is that you have to set the hard height of the row or else the children won't know there are dimensions to render against:

```
<div class="row center-block">    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 " >
      <div id="buttonWrapper1"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ">
        <div id="buttonWrapper2"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ">
         <div id="buttonWrapper3"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 ">
         <div id="buttonWrapper4"></div>
    </div>
</div>



.row { height:100px; }
.col-xs-12 { width:25%; height:100%; position:absolute; float:left; position:relative; }


#buttonWrapper1 {
  height:100%;
    background-image: url('http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02830/cat_2830677b.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

#buttonWrapper2 {
  height:100%;
    background-image: url('http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02830/cat_2830677b.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

#buttonWrapper3 {
  height:100%;
    background-image: url('http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02830/cat_2830677b.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

#buttonWrapper4 { 
  height:100%;
    background-image: url('http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02830/cat_2830677b.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome, but I think something is wrong for me, because when I open this example the kittens faces are half cut off. When I scale it down to the smallest size though, they look correct. What I'm trying to achieve is that everything is visible and proportional in all the browser sizes. Is this an issue with Bootstrap perhaps?

Comment: Adjust the height value on the .row in the codepen to play around with it

Comment: I just set it to 300px... play around with it though, and maybe play around with background-size.  It should get you very close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Wow this great, but is still possible to make it Cols respond. Everything is just in four cols across. I need it be able to break into two columns and 1 at the small level.

Comment: Take this code out ".col-xs-12 { width:25%; height:100%; position:absolute; float:left; position:relative; }".  I just put that in there to simulate Bootstrap in the Codepen I created.  Bootstrap attributes should take over and handle col size for you.

Comment: You can probably override the .col-? selectors to make sure their height is 100% and position is relative.  Everything else I defined for .col-xs-12 in the Codepen can be removed.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yeah I found a solution similar, based on your suggestion. Basically I use a custom class to over ride the default col-xs-12 height for each of my break points.

So it looks something like this:  

`@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    .custom-height{height: 320px !important;} 
}

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 custom-height">        
 <div id="buttonWrapper1"></div></div>`

It's not 100% but it's alot better now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much. Yeah I found a solution similar, based on your suggestion. Basically I use a custom class to over ride the default col-xs-12 height for each of my break points.

As the browser scales I just set the height. Like you said you  have to set the hard height of the row otherwise the children won't know how much to adjust for.

So it looks something like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    .custom-height{height: 320px !important;} 
}

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 custom-height">        
 <div id="buttonWrapper1"></div></div>
```

It's not 100% but it's a lot better now

Comment: If you think my answer was correct please select it. Glad it worked out!